# How to "grep" lines of a file by range of value

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file with timestamps and I want to grep it so that I can see the lines matching 12:30:00 - 12:32:00 . I know that in bash there is the {0..2} for doing something similar but I dont know in grep how to do it?
At the moment I am doing `grep 2015-01-12 12:3{0..2}` but it doesnt work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following for this.

```
grep '2015-01-12 12:3[0-2]'
```

or

```
grep '2015-01-12 12:3[0,1,2]'
```

I hope it helps.